# Intent does not start activity

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have set a alarm through alarm manager to start a IntentService on a specific time.

In IntentService running some checks and starting an Intent to activity JobDetails.

In JobDetails clicking on a button leads to another activity JobField.
On completing the JobField -> JobListing is opened.

JobListing is a ListView activity which consist of all the jobs. On clicking a list item i.e job, JobDetails is opened.

Flow

Application does not exist in recent apps.

AlarmManger triggers -> IntentService -> JobDetails -> JobField -> JobListing **-> JobDetails**

The last intent doest start my JobDetails activity.

Entry in **logcat**

```
Activity_launch_request id:com.xx.app time:105238474
```

Code

**IntentService**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobDetails.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**JobListing**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobDetails.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: put some Log.v in intent service to see if the execution reaches there

Comment: try to replace `context` with `CLASS_NAME.this`

Comment: @Daniele This particular intent does not work only in this condition. Be it any other flow this intent is working.

Comment: @Pooya intent service is triggered. It is later intent which does not start.

Comment: update your menifest.....

Answer (score 0):

Add JobDetails to your activity manifest in AndroidManifest.xml and then use getActivity() as your context